# IntelliJ IDEA cannot resolve static import

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, static-import

When I import regularly it works as expected:

[image]

However, if I change an import to `static`, IDEA cannot resolve it:

[image]

Gradle builds the project successfully.

It seems to be a problem with IDEA but I can't find if it is a known problem. I tried cleaning, invalidate caches etc. Anything else I can do?

Im using `IntelliJ IDEA community 2016.2.4` and java version `1.7.0_79`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You either want to do this, which will **import** **all** of the **static** **members** of Assert

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

Or, to **get** a **specific** **method**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
```

Comment: I see, thanks. Any idea why gradle had no problem building the project?

Comment: @Thomm I don't really know, on a side note though, what I normally do in intellij is just write in my test `assertEquals()` it will show an error, then I do Alt+Enter, then the context will ask if you want to do a static import, then will find it in Assert

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong - static imports are for static methods, not for classes. I'm guessing you meant to statically import all the methods belonging to `org.junit.Assert`:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```